# How can i use promise that coming from another page in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have 2 pages in my controller folder like this:

General.js

```
const Person = require('../models/person');
let personInfo = new Promise((success,reject)=>{
  Person.find({ Group: 'pre'})
    .then((par) => {
      if (par.length > 0) {
        success(par);
      } else {
        reject("Error");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
});
module.exports.personInfo = personInfo;
```

Account.js

```
    exports.Ac = (req, res, next) => {
    let person = new require('./general');
    person.personInfo
    .then((par) => {
      return res.render('/myPage/Account', {
        title: 'Account',
        group: par
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
  }
```

Problem is , this promise working when server beginning but only once after its not working , par value always being same. If i change datas on my database , datas not changing on my web page.

Comment: Put your Promise in a function that returns it, then call this function. `const personInfo = () => new Promise(...); module.exports = personInfo` and in account.js : `personInfo().then(...)`

Comment: I really thank you its worked ,  i tried before this with curly braces it didn't work but i tried like your solution now its working.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome. If you use curly braces you need to add `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**anti-pattern**

This is the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/633183) -

```js
let personInfo = new Promise((success,reject)=>{
  Person.find({ Group: 'pre'})
    .then((par) => {
      if (par.length > 0) {
        success(par);
      } else {
        reject("Error");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
});
```

You can replace it with -

```js
let personInfo = Person.find({ Group: 'pre'})
  .then((par) => {
    if (par.length > 0) {
      return par
      } else {
        throw Error("Error: empty par");
      }
    })
  .catch(console.error)  // <- don't catch here
```

And you should probably leave the `.catch` off and expect the caller to handle error handling. The `.catch` handler below would never trigger if the error is `catch`'d before

```js
exports.Ac = (req, res, next) => {
  let person = new require('./general');
  person.personInfo
    .then((par) => {
      res.render('/myPage/Account', {  // no "return" needed
        title: 'Account',
        group: par
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); }); // <- keep catch here
}
```

The reason it is only happening once, is because Promises can only be resolved or rejected once. You'll have to replace `personInfo` with a function -

```js
const Person = require('../models/person');

const fetchPersonInfo = () =>
  Person.find({ Group: 'pre'})
    .then((par) => {
      if (par.length > 0) {
        return par
      } else {
        throw Error("Error: empty par");
      }
    })
});

module.exports.fetchPersonInfo = fetchPersonInfo;
```

**async await**

You might also want to consider reading up on `async`/`await` as they make your life a lot better

```js
const Person = require('../models/person');

async function fetchPersonInfo () {              // <- async
  const par = await Person.find({ Group: 'pre'}) // <- await
  if (par.length > 0)
    return par;
  else
    throw Error("Error: empty par");
});

module.exports.fetchPersonInfo = fetchPersonInfo;
```

```js
const { fetchPersonInfo } = new require('./general');  // <- top-level import

exports.Ac = async (req, res, next) => {  // <- async
  try {
    const par = await fetchPersonInfo()   // <- await
    res.render('/myPage/Account', {
      title: 'Account',
      group: par
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```